# Grep only those lines with "<active>...</active>" whose next line contains specific tag and value

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, terminal, xml

By using `grep` I only want those lines out of all xml files that contains `<active>true</active>` tags and the next line after that should be `<codePool>community</codePool>`.

A sample XML file would be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Company_Module2 />
            </depends>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

But there are many like this files in the folder, the XML structure is same.

My current `grep` command is:

```
grep -rl '<active>true</active>' --include='*.xml' --color=always
```

How can I achieve this in command line searching ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep

Comment: With some sample XML, I can give you a better answer. `grep` is not the right tool for this job - `XML` is not a regular language.

Comment: @Sobrique well my need is to do this in SSH Remote Terminal, where I cannot install any third party XML command line tool, so can you suggest how to do this with `sed` ?

Comment: @VickyDev Installing a proper XML parsing tool like XMLStarlet is always possible. Have a talk with the admin about it, or install it in your home directory. You can run most parts of a Unix system from a home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all XML files are in the current directory and matches the pattern `*.xml`, and that it's the *filenames* that you want of the files that contains the specified XML:

```
$ xml sel -t -i '/config/modules/Company_Module[active = "true" and codePool = "community"]' -f -nl ./*.xml
```

This uses [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (`xml`, but sometimes installed as `xmlstarlet`) which is a command line XML parsing tool.

It tries to match the specified XPath expression and, if it matches, outputs the filename of the input file that contained the matching XML.

Since it's using an XML parser, it's independent of the ordering of the tags within the `<Company_Module>` node.

Comment: cool. In my Linux  machine the command is installed under the name of `xmlstarlet sel -t -i ....`

Answer (score -1):

Well I didn't want to leave `grep` command which I have used for so long.

So I found a way to do that with just below thingy:

```
grep -rzl '<active>true</active>.*<codePool>community</codePool>' --include='*.xml' --color=always
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -A1 "<active>" *.xml
```

A1 -> print the pattern and next line.